# how to actually $rootScope.$applyAsync(); work?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-digest

I use **$rootScope.$applyAsync();** bottom last of function. is it possible **$rootScope.$applyAsync();** upside code run after downside code? e.g.

```
var arr = [5, 42, 456, 120, 00, 250, 14, 80, 70, 120, 100];
var index;
function applyFun(){
    setIndex(10);
    $rootScope.$applyAsync();
    getIndex();
}

function setIndex(ind){
    index = ind;
}

function getIndex(){
  console.log(arr[index]); // is it possible sometime 'index' is undefined? because it's
}

applyFun();
```

I think it's not possible? but any one know please help me.

Comment: Can you please explain more what you have issues?

Comment: issue is sometime index value not set and get output is undefined.

Comment: What is the meaning of sometimes? Please post that test case.  I just test your code and I did not get undefined any time.

Comment: sorry @MohitSaxena my question is how to work  '$rootScope.$applyAsync();'. is '$rootScope.$applyAsync();' work for only upside code block or not?